# How to integrate a step function to API gateway using CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

What parameters should be passed to AwsIntegration class to integrate a Gateway to a step function using CDK.

Comment: What did you try so far? Share with us the code so we could help

Comment: Right now I have a gateway that has an enpoint connecting to a Lambda.  I would like it to call a step function instead. The Lambda integration is this.api.root.addMethod('POST', new LambdaIntegration(route.lambda, {
                    allowTestInvoke: false
                }), {
                    authorizationType: AuthorizationType.CUSTOM,
                    authorizer: {
                        authorizerId: authorizer.ref
                    }
                });

Comment: Please edit your original post with the code

Comment: @VVictor did you find the answer for this ?